# Address is undefined after deploying a smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment

I tried deploying a greeter contract as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcnJ6.png) , I thought the deployment is suceess but i am unable to get the address of the contract, it always shows **undefined**.

When I tried to execute the greet method it also shows **undefined**

pls check the attached image.

- geth version 1.5.3-stable-978737f5
- solidity version - 0.4.6

I also did unlocking the account and waited for over 10 mins to let it mine.

below are the steps I did to compile and deploy the contract.

```
var greeterSource1 = 'contract mortal { address owner; function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner); } } contract greeter1 is mortal { string greeting; function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } }'

var greeterCompiled1 = web3.eth.compile.solidity(greeterSource1)

var _greeting1 = "Hello World!"

var greeterContract1 = web3.eth.contract(greeterCompiled1.greeter1.info.abiDefinition)

var greeter1 = greeterContract1.new(_greeting1,{from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: greeterCompiled1.greeter1.code, gas: 300000}, 
function(e, contract) {

    if(!e) {
        if(!contract.address) {
            console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");

        } else {
            console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
            console.log(contract);
        }
    }
})
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. [image]

Comment: Hey. If possible, please **avoid posting screenshots of code or terminal outputs**. This will never show up on search engines and wont help users with the same issue like you have. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can only call functions after the transaction has been mined. So inside your callback not just after calling the new function since that'll return instantly.

Add some code in your callback to check for errors, when it's mined you can call the function. You might want to check out [Truffle framework](http://truffleframework.com/) which makes life a bit easier.

Comment: i did wait for more that 10 min to get the contract mined with no luck.I think the deployment failed. how to  check logs, i am connecting via putty to my ethereum transaction node.

Comment: it should be in the error argument. The 'e' in your callback. Pending transactions can be viewed if you connect with geth (geth attach) and then view eth.pendingTransactions. You could also try by adding a gasprice when you create the contract.

Comment: found out the reason, it says my account is locked. so i unlocked the account before executing the contract deployment statement. do i need to unlock the account in every ssh session? because i did unlock in my previous session.

Comment: Yes you do. If you are just testing you could use this client instead: https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc

Answer (score 1):

thanks to benny, I found the issue by changing the above code to log the error

```
 var greeter1 =
 greeterContract1.new(_greeting1,{from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data:
 greeterCompiled1.greeter1.code, gas: 300000}, function(e, contract){
 if(!e) {
   if(!contract.address) {
     console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
   } else {
     console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
     console.log(contract);
   }     
}   else{   console.log(e);     
     }  
     })
```

Issue is that my account is locked, unlocked using below statement 
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0],"yourpassword").

After executing the deployment statement you will get 2 responses
1. It says your contract is being mined, few seconds later
2. Address to your contract
Now I got my address to the contract.